# Is there an R function to find the index of regexp matches in a character vector?

Tags: regex, r, match

I'm looking for an R function that works like `match` only for regular expression matching instead of equality. In other words, if I have a variable `r` that is a character vector of regular expressions and a variable x which is a character vector, I want the function to return a numeric vector the same length as `r` that gives, for each regular expression, the index of the first element that matches that regular expression. Note that I don't want the position within the string where the regular expression matches. I want the index of the *element* that matches each regular expression.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're just looking for `grep`:

```
x <- c("arm","foot","lefroo", "bafoobar")
r <- c("ar","^ba","$m","foo")
```

Get the first regex match index:

```
sapply(r, function(y) grep(y,x)[1])

 ar ^ba  $m foo 
  1   4  NA   2
```

Get all regex match indexes:

```
sapply(r, function(y) grep(y,x))

$ar
[1] 1 4 # returns matches of ar in x

$`^ba`
[1] 4

$`$m`
integer(0)

$foo
[1] 2 4
```

Comment: Wait, according to the help page for grep, don't you need `value=FALSE` to have it return the indices?

Comment: Also, is there a function that takes a vector of regexps or do I just have to use sapply as demonstrated?

Comment: `value = FALSE` is the default for `grep`. I'm not aware of another function whose arguments are a character vector and a vector of regex strings. Besides, these types of problems are exactly what the `*apply` series of functions are designed to solve.